# Mysql changes 0 to NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have text field in my database table. It will contain, some content of my website. This content has also some opening hours. And during the updating the field mysql changes 9:00 to 9NULL. How can I prevent this ?

this is my update query:

```
 $data = $db->query("UPDATE `pages` SET `pl`='$pl' WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

EDIT:

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `pl` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `en` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `de` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `ru` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is the value of `$p1` ? I'm betting it's `9NULL`

Comment: show us the table definition also

Comment: The $pl contains some text like:

Monday-Friday: 9:00 - 17:00. When I save, it changes to Monday-Friday: 9NULL - 17NULL

Comment: Don't know if it is the problem, but for prepared queries pdo does use a leading colon to indicate parameter names. Without a parameter named :00 the query could insert NULL.

Comment: Anyone has a solution ?